# iScroll.js and iOS browser detection - show the iScroll.js file only to iPad/iPhone

Tags: php, javascript, iphone, ipad, mobile-safari

I've created a page that uses fixed positioning for header and footer and has to work also on iPad/iPhone. I'm using iScroll.js (http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) for scrolling the page on iPad/iPhone. However, I need this script to work only on iOS (pages are simple HTML pages), example: http://projects.klavina.com/iscroll/

**Question:**
I would like to show the JS (in the head area of the HTML document) only to iOS devices (something like Conditional Comments for IE). How can I do that? Is this possible with Javascript? If not, can I use PHP? I don't do any back-end programming, but I believe I could figure that out if you point me in the right direction.

Thank you!

Comment: IMO, I like the ability to drag-scroll on that page. It probably doesn't work as well in other cases, but it makes sense for a photo gallery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As detailed in the [Safari Web Content Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006517-SW3), you can use the user agent to determine if you are on an iOS device. You can easily test this in either JavaScript or PHP. Here is a JavaScript example:

```
userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
if(/iPhone/.test(userAgent) || /iPod/.test(userAgent) || /iPad/.test(userAgent)) {
    // load iScroll here
}
```

Comment: For extra brevity, you can reduce that down to a single RegExp: `/iP(hone|od|ad)/.test(userAgent)`